# Which Xorg driver (not kernel driver) to use with GMA500/Poulsbo video hardware in 12.04

Tags: xorg, gma500, drivers, poulsbo

I have a Asus EeePC with a GMA500 video card. I followed the instructions on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo/, which made the netbook boot correctly. Without any xorg.conf file, Xorg uses the VESA driver, which is quite slow. Manually specifying `fbdev` as driver in xorg.conf also works. Which one should I use? Are there any other drivers for Xorg that do better at 2d accelleration (since the kernel driver doesn't support 3d acceleration)?

Comment: Have you read this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1984236 and this too http://askubuntu.com/a/52435/63025

Answer (score 1):

Of the two, fbdev is much faster than VESA. According to a post deep in the thread on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1984236 fbdev is the right choice if no 3d acceleration is available, but other than that I couldn't find any authoritative references.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the modesetting driver, or the EMGD from the joggler's  and jools repositories. EMGD 1.14 driver will give you a hardware acceleration.